# Install Ubuntu without mouse: Please help

Tags: drivers, touchpad

So, I will keep it quick. I want to install ubuntu, but seems like my touchpad doesn't work until I download drivers, and I only have one USB port so a mouse is not an option. Does anybody know a version or a way of Ubuntu where I can just install it with only keyboard? My mouse is Synaptics.
EDIT: I am installing the system, I don't have access to terminal

Comment: Please describe the actual problem you are having.  At what point in the installation do you think you need a mouse?

Comment: The beginning... I think the window of  the installation is not focused so I cant select buttons

Comment: Try using the `TAB` key to select different options and `ENTER` to continue.

Comment: doesn't workkkk

Comment: It should.... I suggest reviewing the keyboard navigation information posted in the answer by @jitter ... I'm assuming this is a laptop with a built in keyboard since there is a touchpad, so why can't you use the USB port for a mouse?

Comment: The post says that I only have one.

Comment: Yes I saw that. Why can't you use it for a mouse? What else do you need to have plugged in during system installation?

Comment: The system installation USB

Comment: Have you tried using arrow keys?

Comment: If there is an SD card reader you could run the installation from that. If there is only one port you could also use a USB hub. But I think the best path is to study the keyboard navigation shortcuts, because they do work for system installation, assuming your keyboard works.  It's also possible that you aren't noticing the keyboard navigation working because it can be very subtle to see when something is selected.

Comment: Seems like this hardware might be a poor choice to install Ubuntu upon.

Comment: Try the space key. I know, it's backwards, but to install with just the keyboard you use tab and arrows to navigate and the space key works as the enter key. It is what it is. (I've tested the upcoming release installation with just a keyboard before and it's not a good experience. It can be done, but hopefully it's a simple installation and not requiring advanced partitioning or the likes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "MinimalCD" is exactly what you want.

The installer is keyboard only, so disconnect your mouse.

Download the Ubuntu 20.04 "mini.iso" file from the following location and create a bootable USB with it.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/

Then boot into this USB.

Note: The "MinimalCD" installer requires a **Non**-UEFI system. You may need to boot into your BIOS and set it to boot in Legacy mode. If your computer only uses UEFI, the "MinimalCD" installer will not work.

The mini.iso is only 78 MB in size because it will download all of the Ubuntu installation files as needed.

The benefit for you is that the installer is keyboard only. Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, and <kbd>↓</kbd> keys to navigate; use the <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to make selections or the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to undo selections.

After booting into the ISO, select the first option...

[image: MinimalCD 1st Screen]

Here is an example of what the installation screens look like...

[image: MinimalCD 2nd Screen]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the visual installer, you should be able to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the selectable buttons, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select that option. This site should be able to help you out greatly for this. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-nav.html.en

Comment: Sorry. But it doesn't work. I don't think the window of installation is currently focused.

Comment: @NeonFoxer you can use `super + tab` to switch between windows.

Comment: What is the super key?

Comment: Wait... strange. These keys don't work.

Comment: @NeonFoxer typically your "windows" key. if that doesnt work, it should be in that general area.

Comment: @NeonFoxer can you try `alt + f2`? this should open the terminal.

Comment: Yep. But it seems everything works. I can adjust the brightness. But the combination of the Windows key and Tab do nothing at all.

Comment: Jitter alt+f2 doesnt work

Comment: does your laptop have a cd player?

Comment: no it doesn't :(

Comment: i got nothing then. your best bet is to see if you have a usb hub lying around so you can have an extra temporary usb slot